# How to whitelist services on Openshift route

Tags: openshift, whitelist

I know it's possible to whitelist IP-addresses for a route, but can you whitelist services by their name?

Running OpenShift 3.9.

Looking for a native solution that does not require external solutions like Istio, Nginx, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i understood your question correctly that you want to whitelist clients by dns name.
as far as i understand the docs from Openshift 3.9 [1] and the docs from HAProxy [2], i cannot see any option in HAProxy itself to build acls with dns names of the clients.
The only option available is ip whitelisting.

[1] https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/architecture/networking/routes.html#whitelist

[2] https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.3